# Pseudocoefficients and Traces of Standard Representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{R}$ (you may assume that $G/Z(G)$ is anisotropic if necessary) and suppose $\pi$ is a discrete series representation of $G(\mathbb{R})$ with central character $\chi$. Let $f: G(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f\chi^{-1}$ factors through $G(\mathbb{R})/A_G(\mathbb{R})^0$ (where $A_G$ is the maximal $\mathbb{R}$-split subtorus of $Z(G)$) and this factorization is compactly supported. Further, suppose $f$ is a pseudo-coefficient for $\pi$. Namely, if $\pi'$ is a tempered irreducible representation of $G(\mathbb{R})$ with the same central character $\chi$ then

$$\mathrm{tr}\,\pi'(f)=\begin{cases}1 & \mbox{if}\quad \pi\cong\pi'\\ 0 & \mbox{if}\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
where, here, since $f$ is not necessarily compactly supported we define $\mathrm{tr}\, \pi'(f)$ to be the trace of the operator
$$v\mapsto \int_{G(\mathbb{R})/A_G(\mathbb{R})^0}f(g)\pi(g)(v)\, dg$$
which is well-defined by our assumptions.

I have two questions:

1) I would like to verify that for $\pi'$ a standard representation (as in the context of the Langlands Classification--essentially an induction of a tempered representation) that $\mathrm{tr} \,\pi'(f)=0$ unless $\pi' \cong \pi$. A reference for this fact would be much appreciated.

2) I would like to find a reference for the fact that the orbital integral of the semsimple element $\gamma$, $\mathcal{O}_{\gamma}(f)$, should equal $0$ if $\gamma$ is not elliptic and $\Theta_{\pi}(\gamma^{-1})$ otherwise.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think there is a relatively accessible formula (a sum over a Weyl-group-type set) for $\operatorname{tr} \pi'(f)$ when $\pi'$ is induced.  That may be a place to start for (1).

Comment: Also, for compact (or just compact-modulo-centre) groups, I think that a pseudo-coefficient is (modulo functions annihilated by invariant distributions) just a coefficient, in which case your (2) is a standard fact in the representation theory of compact groups (all $\gamma$ being elliptic).

Comment: @LSpice Many thanks for your response! Could you point me to references for the results you mentioned?

Comment: I was thinking of [van Dijk - Computation of certain induced characters of $p$-adic groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01429876) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=338277)); I imagine something similar applies in the real case.  However, this is for parabolic induction, and anisotropic (modulo centre) groups don't have proper parabolics, so maybe this is not relevant for you.

Comment: For the orbital-integral fact, note that $\operatorname{tr} \pi'(f) = \operatorname{tr} \pi'(\overline{\Theta_\pi})$ for all representations $\pi'$ (no extra assumptions in the aniso-mod-centre case); so, since characters are dense in invariant distributions, $\mathcal O_\gamma(f) = \mathcal O_\gamma(\overline{\Theta_\pi}) = \Theta_\pi(\gamma^{-1})$ for all $\gamma$.